# Get two nibbles from a byte in Ruby

Tags: ruby, byte, nibble

What's the easiest way to get two nibbles (as Integers) from a byte in Ruby?

Comment: What have you tried? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble#Extracting_a_nibble_from_a_byte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the "byte" is a number between 0 and 255:

```
n1, n2 = (byte & 0xf0) >> 4, byte & 0x0f
```